# How to use the Random library?

Tags: java

How can i set these values using the Random to a random decimal number that is between 0 and 100?

```
xPos = Math.round((Math.random() * 100) * 10) / 10;
yPos = Math.round((Math.random() * 100) * 10) / 10;
```

i am trying to set the values xPos and yPos to random decimals between 0 and 100

Comment: Check [Java Generate Random Number Between Two Given Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271598/java-generate-random-number-between-two-given-values)

Comment: What is your problem, exactly? Why not just crate an instance of `Random` and use the [`nextInt(int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained

Comment: What do you mean by random decimal number? If you just want a random `double` in the range [0, 100) then you can use `xPos = Math.random() * 100`.

Comment: How precise do you want the output to be?  One decimal place?

Comment: What type are `xPos` and `yPos`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
double xPos = rand.nextDouble() * 100;
double yPos = rand.nextDouble() * 100;
```

[`nextDouble docs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble())

Answer (score -1):

To generate a random decimal from [0-100) you can use Math.random() as you are already, or you can use a `Random` object

Do note by [0-100), these bits of code return numbers from 0 up to, but not including, 100

---

Math.random():

```
double xPos = Math.random() * 100;
double yPos = Math.random() * 100;
```

Math.random() with 1 decimal place:

```
double xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) / 10;
double yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) / 10;
```

Random object:

```
Random r = new Random();
double xPos = r.nextDouble() * 100;
double yPos = r.nextDouble() * 100;
```

Random object with 1 decimal place:

```
Random r = new Random();
double xPos = r.nextInt(1000) / 10.0;
double yPos = r.nextInt(1000) / 10.0;
```

---

It is considered better practice to use the `Random` object, even though `Math.random()` calls its own internal `Random` object.

Using `Random` instead of `Math.random()` does have the benefit of easier concurrency.  Without multiple `Random` objects, multithreading with heavy usage of randomized numbers will slow down to a crawl

Comment: how do you also round the random()?

Comment: @kaanmote What do you need it rounded to?  I have included one decimal place answers which you can scale to two or more.  Do you need to round to the nearest half? the nearest int?

Comment: No explanation for the downvote?  One does not help others improve without saying how