# Android: Automatically get the next list item every second

Tags: java, android, listview, autocomplete, android-edittext

I got a `listView` with the values `1000 to 9000` (1000 a step).
My idea is that the user should pick one item from the list and than press the **start** button. The chosen item will be displayed in the `editText`.
After the user pressed the start button the `editText` will take the following `listItem` item as value **every second** until the user presses the **cancel** button.

So if the user for example choses `3000` and than press start, the `editText` should state 3000, and increment by 1000 every second (taking over the next `listItem`).

**Idea how it should be:**
[image: Preview]

Comment: Is this because of grammar or sentence construction, the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Only first choice should be random, and than cycle trough the list starting with that random item? or should it be a random list item every second?

Comment: The 'ListView' is displayed with 'value' starting from '1000 to 9000'. If user select 1000 value and click on start button then the 'EditText'  after delay of 1 sec autochoose 2000 'value' then 3000 'value' then 4000 value in 'EditText' from given 'ListView' value list.

Comment: Sorry my edit wasn't correct. I have changed it. please correct me if I didn't get your question quite right.

Answer (score 1):

> My approach to get done  would be

1) Generate random number between 0 & adapter count.[Generate Random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271598/java-generate-random-number-between-two-given-values)

2) Write method to access text from adapter on basis of random number

3) For counties lopping use `Handler` run `Handler` till user press

**e.g Handler**

```
handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       if(!userClcikedCancel){
            handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
            // get text from adapter and set to EditText     
       }
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```