# new Random().nextInt(999999) sometimes generates 5 digit number

Tags: java, random

I am using new `Random().nextInt(999999)` to generate a 6 digit random number. But sometimes it generates 5 digit numbers. And I explicitly have to check if generated number is not 6 digit.

Why this method does that? And is there any other way to be pretty sure it generate only 6 digit random number.

Comment: Because there are five-digit numbers between 0 and 999999.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any research.  Please [edit] your question to include the research you have done and *precisely* where you are having difficulty.  If you can do this, I may retract my downvote.

Comment: i have no words to praise your comment @JoeC ^_^

Comment: Take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271598/java-generate-random-number-between-two-given-values

Comment: I don't want to depress you, but it can  also generate 4-, 3-, 2-, and 1-digit numbers.

Comment: Please delete my answer as it has already been asked. I cannot delete it and it's getting down voted.

Comment: What do you mean you can't delete your own answer?

Comment: When I try to do that, it says **You cannot delete the question**.

Answer (score 4):

`Random().nextInt(999999)` generates number between 0 and 999998, so you have ~10% chance to get number smaller than 100000 (5 and less digits).

Try

```
100000 + Random().nextInt(900000)
```

you will get number in range 100000 - 999999

Comment: [`Random.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) returns a value **exclusive** to the limit.

Comment: This answer is correct except Random().nextInt(999999) generates number between 0 and **999998**

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, Fatih Ozcan thanks, I fixed my answer

Comment: Can someone please delete the question,please?

Comment: @MehrajMalik Why? It has an upvoted answer that will help others as well.

Comment: @ModusTollens My question is continuously being down voted and eating my reputations, that's why. And because it's duplicate

Comment: @MehrajMalik Questions that have an upvoted answer cannot be deleted because it would delete the answer as well, and that would be unfair to the users who answered. You can try to make your question more specific by editing it, that might get it reopened. You could also ask to have your question disassociated from your account by using the "contact us" link in this sites footer.

Comment: When I try to hover at **delete** option. it says **Two more votes needed to delete the question** someone has already requested to delete as it shows me **delete(1)**.

Answer (score 0):

`Random().nextInt(999999)` generates 5 digits number sometimes, because it generates random values between 0 and 999999.

Use the following snippet for generating random numbers in a range:

```
Random random = new Random();
minimum + random.nextInt(maximum - minimum + 1);
```