# How would I get a random number between 10^(n-1) and (10^n)-1?

Tags: java

I thought about using a loop and generating a random number inside it until the number is in the right range but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: When unsure of whether some code is ideal for a given problem, posting the code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com would be the recommended option.

Comment: what have you tried ? where you stuck up, Show us some effort

Comment: this question is duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271598/java-generate-random-number-between-two-given-values

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
new Random().nextInt(max- min) + min
```

to generate the number between ranges

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, I'm a complete beginner. Wouldn't I have to generate a random number 'n' and then use Math.pow to get 10^n-1 or something along those lines? Could I plug 10^(n-1) and (10^n)-1 straight into the random generator?