# Java method that generates random numbers passed by instance variables

Tags: java, oop

I am working on making a text based game in Java, I am using a class and instance variables and I am trying to create a method that generates a random number based on the number that the instance variable `max_attack` has.

```java
public class badPlayer 
{
    String description;
    int health;
    int award;
    int max_attack;

    public badPlayer(String description, int health, int award, int attack){            
        this.description=description;
        this.health = health;
        this.award = award;
        this.max_attack = attack;
    }

   Random rnd = new Random();

    public int maxAttack(){ 
        int rand_int1 = rnd.nextInt(max_attack);
        return rand_int1;   
    }   
}

public class troll extends badPlayer
{
    troll(int attack){
        super("troll", 100, 50, 100);
    } 
}
```

**Output**

> troll1005089

I would like the method to create random numbers between 1 and 100.

Comment: By convention, class names start with an upper case letter. Consider naming your classes as `BadPlayer` and `Troll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Random r = new Random();
int low = 1;
int high = 100;
int result = r.nextInt(high-low) + low;
```

[Java Generate Random Number Between Two Given Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271598/java-generate-random-number-between-two-given-values)

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = 1 + random.nextInt(100);
```

result - random number from 1 to 100
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--